# Firestore not working inside Android Service with no error?

Tags: android, firebase, service, google-cloud-firestore, foreground

Hello firebase is not working inside a foreground service no matter what I do

```
db.collection("user").document(userDocumentId).collection("devices").
            document(deviceDocumentId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,
                            @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {...
```

its as simple as that the same call returns all data inside the activity but inside firebase there is nothing returned???

documentSnapshot.get("apps")

returns null inside service but inside any activity returns value from server.

Is there a particular way to use firestore from within a service?

```
<service
        android:name=".background.SensorService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.bgfirebaseapp.FirebaseBackgroundService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

this is my xml also nothing unusual??!!

any help please?